# What are the appropriate places to call different scheduling android components

Tags: android, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, timertask

I need to know which android component I should use for scheduling a task, I need to execute a task which will update application data from server in every 3 minutes (Hence I cannot use JobScheduler or SyncAdapter both are restricted to minimum of 15 minutes poll interval).

So what are best alternative?

1. TimerTask
2. Handler
3. ThreadPoolExecuter
4. ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

If possible kindly elaborate where should we use those components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Android-Job** library from Evernote

```
implementation 'com.evernote:android-job:1.2.6'
```

A utility library for Android to run jobs delayed in the background. 
Depending on the Android version either the JobScheduler, GcmNetworkManager or AlarmManager is getting used

**Usage**
The class **JobManager** serves as entry point. 
Your jobs need to extend the class **Job**. 
Create a **JobRequest** with the corresponding builder class and schedule this request with the **JobManager**.

Before you can use the **JobManager** you must initialize the singleton.
You need to provide a Context and add a JobCreator implementation after that.

The JobCreator maps a job tag to a specific job class. It's recommended to initialize the JobManager in the **onCreate()** method of your Application object, but there is an alternative, if you don't have access to the Application class.

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        JobManager.create(this).addJobCreator(new DemoJobCreator());
    }
}

public class DemoJobCreator implements JobCreator {

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public Job create(@NonNull String tag) {
        switch (tag) {
            case DemoSyncJob.TAG:
                return new DemoSyncJob();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

After that you can start scheduling jobs.

```
public class DemoSyncJob extends Job {

    public static final String TAG = "job_demo_tag";

    @Override
    @NonNull
    protected Result onRunJob(Params params) {
        // run your job here
        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }

    public static void scheduleJob() {
        new JobRequest.Builder(DemoSyncJob.TAG)
                .setExecutionWindow(30_000L, 40_000L)
                .build()
                .schedule();
    }
}
```

This is an advanced version of Default Job Scheduler in android and have great capabilities than the default one which is having a lot of limitations and back ward compatibility.